# Multiple Google events from multiple text boxes

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a form that will hold multiple Google Calendar events in multiple text boxes, the user should be able to add another text box to hold another event. As each text box is created its name will incremented from the last e.g. textbox1, textbox2 etc. The code below shows the code I have so far, I can't seem to make it work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
function doGet(){

 var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('QuickAdd Events');
 //Create a penel which holds all the form elelemnts
 var parent = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('parent');
 var left = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('left').setWidth(200);
 var right = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('right');

 var noOfEvents = app.createTextBox().setName('noOfEvents').setValue(1).setWidth(30); 

 var eventTitleLabel = app.createLabel('Event Title:');
 var eventTitle = app.createTextBox().setName('eventTitle').setWidth(200);  
 var eventButton = app.createButton('Create Events');
 var childButton = app.createButton('+ Event');

 left.add(noOfEvents)
     .add(eventTitleLabel)
     .add(eventTitle);

 right.add(eventButton)
      .add(childButton);

 var eventHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('createEvents');
 eventHandler.addCallbackElement(left);
 eventButton.addClickHandler(eventHandler); 

 var panelHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('createAnotherEvent');
 panelHandler.addCallbackElement(left);
 childButton.addClickHandler(panelHandler);

 parent.add(left)
       .add(right);

 app.add(parent);
 app.close();
 return app;
}


function createAnotherEvent(e){
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

 var numberOfEvents = app.getElementById("noOfEvents");
 numberOfEvents++;
 app.getElementById('noOfEvents').setValue(numberOfEvents);
 var eventTitleLabel = app.createLabel('Event Title:');
 var eventTitle = app.createTextBox().setName('eventTitle'+numberOfEvents).setWidth(200);
 //the new textBox has a new predictable name and you can easily get it in the handler

 app.getElementById('left').add(eventTitleLabel)
                           .add(eventTitle);
 return app;
}

function createEvents(e){
 Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

 try{
  var numberOfEvents = Number(e.parameter.noOfEvents);
  for (var i = 1; i < numberOfEvents; i++) {

   var event = e.parameter[eventTitle+i];;

   var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
   cal.createEventFromDescription(event);

   app.add(app.createLabel('Event created Successfully'));
   }
   //make the form panel invisible
  app.getElementById('parent').setVisible(false);
  return app;
 }

 //If an error occurs, show it on the panel
 catch(e){
  app.add(app.createLabel('Error occured: '+e));
  return app;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(I don't have time right now to check everything but here is an error I saw...)*

In this function :

```
function createAnotherEvent(e){
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

 var numberOfEvents = app.getElementById("noOfEvents");
```

You are trying to get the value in a widget but what you get is the widget itself (as a UiApp object) so you can't use `numberOfEvents++;` that is a method for numbers...

To get a widget value use `var numberOfEvents = Number(e.parameter.numberOfEvents);`
because `e.parameter.numberOfEvents` is actually a string.

If ever you have non decimal value in that string you can get rid of it easily using a simple regex like below :
`var numberOfEvents = Number(e.parameter.numberOfEvents.replace(/\D/g,''));` , this way you are sure that only numbers will be passed as value.

---

**EDIT**

*Found the time to go further...*

here is a working version of the code... there were indeed a few details that prevent it to work :

- missing id on noOfEvent
- name of eventTitle was not right (there should be a number added to it because later you setName with numbers
- getting 'var event = e.parameter['eventTitle'+i];' , you forgot the '' to build the name

  ```
  function doGet(){

   var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('QuickAdd Events');
   //Create a penel which holds all the form elelemnts
   var parent = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('parent');
   var left = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('left').setWidth(200);
   var right = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('right');

   var noOfEvents = app.createTextBox().setName('noOfEvents').setId('noOfEvents').setValue(1).setWidth(30); 

   var eventTitleLabel = app.createLabel('Event Title:');
   var eventTitle = app.createTextBox().setName('eventTitle1').setWidth(200);  
   var eventButton = app.createButton('Create Events');
   var childButton = app.createButton('+ Event');

   left.add(noOfEvents)
       .add(eventTitleLabel)
       .add(eventTitle);

   right.add(eventButton)
        .add(childButton);

   var eventHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('createEvents');
   eventHandler.addCallbackElement(left);
   eventButton.addClickHandler(eventHandler); 

   var panelHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('createAnotherEvent');
   panelHandler.addCallbackElement(left);
   childButton.addClickHandler(panelHandler);

   parent.add(left)
         .add(right);

   app.add(parent);
   app.close();
   return app;
  }

  function createAnotherEvent(e){
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var noOfEvents = Number(e.parameter.noOfEvents.replace(/\D/g,''));;
   noOfEvents++;
   app.getElementById('noOfEvents').setValue(noOfEvents);
   var eventTitleLabel = app.createLabel('Event Title:');
   var eventTitle = app.createTextBox().setName('eventTitle'+noOfEvents).setWidth(200);
   //the new textBox has a new predictable name and you can easily get it in the handler

   app.getElementById('left').add(eventTitleLabel)
                             .add(eventTitle);
   return app;
  }

  function createEvents(e){
   Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

   try{
    var noOfEvents = Number(e.parameter.noOfEvents.replace(/\D/g,''));;
    for (var i = 1; i <= noOfEvents; i++) {

     var event = e.parameter['eventTitle'+i];;

     var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
     cal.createEventFromDescription(event);

     app.add(app.createLabel('Event created Successfully'));
     }
     //make the form panel invisible
    app.getElementById('parent').setVisible(false);
    return app;
   }

   //If an error occurs, show it on the panel
   catch(e){
    app.add(app.createLabel('Error occured: '+e));
    return app;   }
  ```

  }

Comment: That helps but it is still saying it can't read the property of numberOfEvents, I call it noOfEvents but that doesn't matter. I add numberOfEvents to the left panel and have the callBackElement to the left panel, so I don't know what the error is. I looked at the execution transcript and it creates the text box and names it eventTitle2 but here is what might be the problem:
`TextBox.setName([eventTitle2])`
`TextBox.setWidth([200])`
`(class).getElementById([left])`
`Label.toString()`
`(class).add([Label])`
`TextBox.toString()`
`(class).add([TextBox])`
`(class).toString()`

Comment: I edited my answer... the last brace doesn't want to get in the code !! SO interface is buggy tonight for me... sorry. It seems to work now. feel free to tell me if something is still wrong. btw thx for accepting.

Comment: Now that the Ui works, I suggest you add something to error trap empty fields bacause the app says that events were created successfully even when nothing is entered... what do you think ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

For better clarity, I added this second answer with a reviewed version of the code in which I added a few validators to handle empty responses , feel free to have a look and comment if needed.

It is not perfect yet but it shows a few possibilities...
[demo here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxUNBpuPuJ_wRJnUiFXgCWRUddSaYuZ1BBusUdHBmbWI-eqNjM/exec)  (neutralized to avoid creating events in my calendar ;)

### code :

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('QuickAdd Events');
  var parent = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('parent').setStyleAttributes({'padding':'25px'});
  var left = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('left').setWidth(200);
  var right = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('right').setStyleAttributes({'paddingLeft':'10px'});
  var noOfEvents = app.createTextBox().setName('noOfEvents').setId('noOfEvents').setValue(1+' event to create').setWidth(110); 
  var eventButton = app.createButton('Create Events').setId('btn').setEnabled(false).setPixelSize(100,30).setStyleAttributes({'borderRadius':'8px'});
  var warning = app.createHTML('<b>warning</b><br>not all events have been defined').setId('warning').setStyleAttributes({'paddingLeft':'10px'});
  var childButton = app.createButton('+ Event').setStyleAttributes({'borderRadius':'5px'});
  var CH = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(eventButton).setEnabled(true).forTargets(warning).setVisible(false);
  var eventTitleLabel = app.createLabel('Event Title:');
  var eventTitle = app.createTextBox().setName('eventTitle1').setWidth(200).addClickHandler(CH);  
  var clrH = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(eventTitle).setText('');
  left.add(noOfEvents)
  .add(eventTitleLabel)
  .add(app.createHorizontalPanel().add(eventTitle).add(app.createButton('clear',clrH).setStyleAttributes({'padding':'0px','borderRadius':'5px'}).setPixelSize(40,17)));

  right.add(app.createHorizontalPanel().add(eventButton)
  .add(warning))
  .add(childButton);

  var eventHandler = app.createServerHandler('createEvents');
  eventHandler.addCallbackElement(left);
  eventButton.addClickHandler(eventHandler); 

  var panelHandler = app.createServerHandler('createAnotherEvent');
  panelHandler.addCallbackElement(left);
  childButton.addClickHandler(panelHandler);

  parent.add(left)
  .add(right);

  app.add(parent);
  app.close();
  return app;
}


function createAnotherEvent(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var eventButton = app.getElementById('btn').setEnabled(false);
  var warning = app.getElementById('warning');
  var noOfEvents = Number(e.parameter.noOfEvents.replace(/\D/g,''));
  noOfEvents++;
  var CH = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(eventButton).setEnabled(true).forTargets(warning).setVisible(false);
  app.getElementById('noOfEvents').setValue(noOfEvents+' events to create');
  var eventTitleLabel = app.createLabel('Event Title:');
  var eventTitle = app.createTextBox().setName('eventTitle'+noOfEvents).setWidth(200).addClickHandler(CH);
  var clrH = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(eventTitle).setText('');
  app.getElementById('warning').setVisible(true)
  app.getElementById('btn')
  app.getElementById('left').add(eventTitleLabel)
  .add(app.createHorizontalPanel().add(eventTitle).add(app.createButton('clear',clrH).setStyleAttributes({'padding':'0px','borderRadius':'5px'}).setPixelSize(40,17)));;
  return app;
}

function createEvents(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var noOfEvents = Number(e.parameter.noOfEvents.replace(/\D/g,''));
  var eventButton = app.getElementById('btn');
  for (var i = 1; i <= noOfEvents; i++) {   
    var event = e.parameter['eventTitle'+i];
    if(event.replace(/ /g,'')==''){eventButton.setEnabled(false) ; app.getElementById('warning').setVisible(true) ; return app }
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= noOfEvents; i++) {   
    var event = e.parameter['eventTitle'+i];
    try{
      var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
 //     cal.createEventFromDescription(event);
      app.add(app.createLabel('Event Nr'+i+' created Successfully'));
    }catch(err){
      app.add(app.createLabel('Event Nr'+i+' : error :'+JSON.stringify(err)));
    }
  }
  //make the form panel invisible
  app.getElementById('parent').setVisible(false);
  return app;
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, that's good you neutralised it or I would have accidentally added loads of events. I already have most of the validators apart from the event button being disabled. I have to hand this work in today at 5, I am glad to get this out of my way ha ha.

Comment: I am trying to implement the setEnabled in my code but I am so tired I can't be bothered ha ha

Comment: Would you know how to implement a Clear button, it would clear the text box for each event? I was thinking of just setting the textbox to "".

Comment: Yes, I have a more complicated create event form with each form in a panel. Each panel has a clear button, I am trying to find out how I can identify which clear button was clicked

Comment: I was thinking of creating a clear function that got the panel and cleared all the text boxes in that panel

Comment: code updated, using client handler (demo updated too...)

Comment: I changed also the label counter, added explicit text

Comment: That is brilliant, thank you so much for your help. I have handed in the work so it can no longer be worked on. I wish I had more time to work on this, I greatly appreciate all the effort and advice you have given.

Comment: You're welcome, this one was an interesting one :-) , I guess it will be helpful to someone else sometime. Anyway, I had fun and that's what matters to me in the end ...